# why does tkinter winfo_width and winfo_height methods return wrong values?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

This is the code. I created a class that inherits from ctk.CTk and i gave it a title and a width of 400 and a height of 400. I also defined some methods that returns the window's width and height.

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class Window(ctk.CTk):
    """
    App window
    """
    def __init__(self, background_color: str, title: str, width: int, height: int):
        super().__init__(fg_color=background_color)
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')

    @property
    def width(self) -> int:
        self.update()
        return self.winfo_width()

    @property
    def height(self) -> int:
        self.update()
        return self.winfo_height()

    def show_window(self):
        """
        displays window
        :return:
        """
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(
        background_color="gray",
        title="test",
        width=400,
        height=400)

    print("width", window.width)
    print("height", window.height)
    window.show_window()
```

if i run the code i get the output;

width 500
height 500

but i specified the width to be 400 and height to be 400

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a solution by using the method wm_geometry method to set the width and height of the window instead of using geometry. For some reason that i don't know customtkinter increases the width and height you specify and it only happens when i use customtkinter and not tkinter.
Now when i try getting the width and height of the window, it gives me the correct values.

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class Window(ctk.CTk):
    """
    App window
    """
    def __init__(self, background_color: str, title: str, width: int, height: int):
        super().__init__(fg_color=background_color)
        self.title(title)
        self.wm_geometry(f'{width}x{height}')

    @property
    def width(self) -> int:
        self.update()
        return self.winfo_width()

    @property
    def height(self) -> int:
        self.update()
        return self.winfo_height()

    def show_window(self):
        """
        displays window
        :return:
        """
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(
        background_color="gray",
        title="test",
        width=400,
        height=400)

    print("width", window. Width)
    print("height", window. Height)
    window.show_window()
```